# How to trigger and handle http POST request with mulitple JSON objects

Tags: go

I am trying to implement Go code with the following change.
Send http POST request with multiple JSON objects using Go and handle the same in response.

Below was my sample code which i wrote.

```
type ReqData struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
    Ok     string `json:"ok"`
}

type RespData struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Number string `json:"number"`
}

type RespData1 struct {
    Employee string `json:"employee"`
    Service  string `json:"service"`
}

type FullResponse struct {
    FullResponse  RespData  `json:"candidate"`
    FullResponse1 RespData1 `json:"employees"`
}

func POST(c *gin.Context) {
    respData := FullResponse{}

    str := RespData{"2222222222", "2222222222"}
    respData.FullResponse = str
    b, _ := json.Marshal(respData)
    respbody1 := string(b)

    respData1 := FullResponse{}
    str1 := RespData1{"111111111111111", "111111"}
    respData1.FullResponse = str1
    c, _ := json.Marshal(respData1)
    respbody2 := string(c)

    respbody := respbody1 + respbody2
    c.String(http.StatusOK, respbody)

}
```

Comment: Note that you need to [*export*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the struct fields, otherwise they will not be un/marshaled by the encoding/json package.

Comment: Tried above sample code but not worked. Please check and help.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do, what kind of json response you're trying to send. Are you trying to send an array with multiple objects? Or a single object which contains multiple child objects? Or send multiple individual objects by themselves? Also in your code there's nothing related to request json handling, all you're doing is creating two strings, concatenating them, and then sending the result in the response.

Comment: Also the names of your types and variables are out of sync, you should try hard to use names that actually make sense in a given context, otherwise your code will be confusing to you and to anyone who is trying to help you.

Comment: I am trying to send a POST request with json having two arrays objects {"Form1":{"name1":"abc","name2":"def"},"Form2":[{"status":"Good","Ok":"okkk"}]} and in response i need to get this response {"candidate":{"name":"abc","number":"123"},"employees":[{"employee":"rajesh","service":"ok"}]}

Comment: To get the response you want you can do something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/a6lkfX5ohgI. As far as the request is concerned you still haven't shown **any** request-specific code, so it is still unclear how you want to send it, e.g. from a browser with javascript, or from an android device with Java, or from a Go client? Show the code you're wrote to send the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220086/discussion-between-andriod-testing-and-mkopriva).

Comment: I have solved this. Thanks for support guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a request type like:

```
    type requestType struct {
       AuthReq1        *authReq1        `json:"auth_req1"`
       AuthReq2        *authReq2        `json:"auth_req2"`
    }
```

now post and handle requestType.

Good luck!

Comment: Tried above sample code but not worked. Please check and help.